# Internal Server Error in flutter when get ID

Tags: flutter, dart

I got an error when I got the ID, namely the Internal Server Error, previously I checked via Postman and it went well as expected, but when I tried to implement it in Flutter, the following error occurred.
Is there anyone here who has a similar case and is exactly the same as the case I experienced.
how do i solve this problem, i've had it for days but it's not done yet.

```
I/flutter ( 7940): 500
I/flutter ( 7940): {"status":"Internal Server Error","code":"500","message":"Internal Server Error","data":{"type":"error","tittle":"Gagal","detail":"SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid: \"card 0\" (SQL: select * from \"ak_peserta_kelas\" where \"id_kelas_kuliah\" = card 0 and \"id_mahasiswa\" = 54806851-a058-4714-b4f8-93dd713d0a96 limit 1) line 712"}}
```

> Here I attach the implementation in my code lists page

```
Widget listJadwal() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Datum>>(
      future: JadwalKuliahProvider.getJadwalKuliah(semester),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 10,
              ),
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var post = (snapshot.data as List<Datum>)[index];
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(
                          10,
                        ),
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                          blurRadius: 9,
                          offset: const Offset(
                            1,
                            2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 16, vertical: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          data[index].nmMk.toString(),
                          style: bold6,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          data[index].dosenAjar.nmDosen.toString(),
                          style: regular7,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          data[index].prodi.toString(),
                          style: regular7,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 30,
                              width: 70,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: const Color(0xffECECEC),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.location_on_outlined,
                                      color: greyColor,
                                      size: 18,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      width: 3,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      data[index].ruangan.toString(),
                                      style: bold6.copyWith(color: greyColor),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 30,
                              width: 110,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: const Color(0xffECECEC),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.watch_later_outlined,
                                      color: greyColor,
                                      size: 18,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      width: 3,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      width: 3,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      data[index].jamAwal.toString(),
                                      style: bold6.copyWith(color: greyColor),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      width: 3,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '-',
                                      style: bold6.copyWith(
                                        color: greyColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      width: 3,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      data[index].jamAkhir.toString(),
                                      style: bold6.copyWith(color: greyColor),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                              width: 100,
                              child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.download,
                                  size: 17,
                                  color: Color(0xffCEE1FF),
                                ),
                                label: Text(
                                  'Materi',
                                  style: bold6,
                                ),
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xff0062FF),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 38,
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      DetailAbsensi(id: "card $index"),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: const Color(0xffC9F7F5),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "Absensi",
                              style: bold5.copyWith(
                                color: const Color(
                                  0xff1BC5BD,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: primaryColor),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

> and here is another page namely detailpage

```
class DetailAbsensi extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailAbsensi({
    super.key,
    this.id = '',
  });
  final String id;

  Future<ModelAbsensi> getDetailAbs(String id) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/absensi_perkuliahan?id_kelas_kuliah=$id',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );

    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return ModelAbsensi.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: CustomAppbar(
          title: 'Absensi Perkuliahan',
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            headerDetail(),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 14,
            ),
            bodyDetail(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget bodyDetail() {
    return FutureBuilder<ModelAbsensi>(
      future: getDetailAbs(id),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(8),
              ),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                  blurRadius: 9,
                  offset: const Offset(
                    1,
                    2,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Table(
                    columnWidths: const {
                      0: FlexColumnWidth(0.5),
                      1: FlexColumnWidth(1.5),
                      2: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                      3: FlexColumnWidth(1.6),
                      4: FlexColumnWidth(1),
                    },
                    children: [
                      TableRow(children: [
                        Column(children: [Text('No', style: bold7)]),
                        Column(children: [Text('Absensi', style: bold7)]),
                        Column(children: [Text('Tanggal', style: bold7)]),
                        Column(children: [Text('Jam', style: bold7)]),
                        Column(children: [Text('Ket', style: bold7)]),
                      ]),
                      TableRow(children: [
                        Column(children: [
                          Text(
                            '1',
                            style: regular7,
                          ),
                        ]),
                        Column(children: [
                          Text(
                            'Masuk',
                            style: regular7,
                          ),
                        ]),
                        Column(children: [
                          Text(
                            '13 Maret 2023',
                            style: regular7,
                          ),
                        ]),
                        Column(children: [
                          Text(
                            '08:00 - 10:00',
                            style: regular7,
                          ),
                        ]),
                        Column(
                          children: const [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.check_rounded,
                              size: 15,
                              color: Colors.green,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ]),
                      TableRow(
                        children: [
                          Column(children: [
                            Text(
                              '2',
                              style: regular7,
                            ),
                          ]),
                          Column(children: [
                            Text(
                              'Masuk',
                              style: regular7,
                            ),
                          ]),
                          Column(children: [
                            Text(
                              '14 Maret 2023',
                              style: regular7,
                            ),
                          ]),
                          Column(children: [
                            Text(
                              '08:00 - 10:00',
                              style: regular7,
                            ),
                          ]),
                          Column(
                            children: const [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.check_rounded,
                                size: 15,
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: primaryColor,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the server logs. It will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: where can i check it?

Comment: print out token and full url in console, see is it the value you expected.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l-ND7vmsj41DHW9wnQEiBIbYL99OnSPQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AndreiVolgin you mean from the back end?

Comment: My bad, I did not notice that your server already told you where the problem is. There is an SQL error. It has nothing to do with Flutter or your app.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin does that mean that what needs to be fixed is on the server side, especially the back end?

Comment: Yes, that's where the error happens.

Comment: but in postman it worked
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wm7LVgDbwKomfsycOldQl51HjlWXfa0r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I would suggest this:
1. Print the full url so you can know if you are building it right.
2. Check which headers are you using in your postman, I see there you have 8 headers but only 1 in your code